# Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Cant add services after having authenticated

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to add google spreadsheet using google drive api in php. But I am getting the following error after authentication.

```
 Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Cant add services after having authenticated' in /var/www/html/spreadsheet/google/src/Google_Client.php:119 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/spreadsheet/google/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php(1046): Google_Client->addService('drive', 'v2') #1 /var/www/html/spreadsheet/index.php(20): Google_DriveService->__construct(Object(Google_Client)) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/spreadsheet/google/src/Google_Client.php on line 119
```

My code:

```
<?php
        require '/var/www/html/spreadsheet/google/src/Google_Client.php';
        require '/var/www/html/spreadsheet/google/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
        require '/var/www/html/spreadsheet/google/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId('xxxxx-vdbo5lga3sq7g8q4g8adgqh72m0ng8ef.apps.googleusercontent.com');
        $client->setClientSecret('BCGuyCPHwNflflBU5jDQ25LQ');
        $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/spreadsheet/index.php');
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

      if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
      if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      } else
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

        $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

        //Inserting a file
        $file = new Google_DriveFile();
        $file->setTitle('Mysheet');
        $file->setDescription('My first sheet through php');
        $file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet');

        $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
              'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
              'uploadType' => 'multipart'
            ));

        print_r($createdFile);

       } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
        exit();
       }
?>
```

Comment: Please remember that your client id should be kept secret at all times.  I have removed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new service, before you authenticate the Client:

```
<?php
// ...

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('clientID');
$client->setClientSecret('clientSecret');
$client->setRedirectUri('redirectURI');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

// create Drive service before authentication
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);


if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Btw: See the [simplefileupload example](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simplefileupload.php) in the google-api-php-client repo.